# c++ - Use derived class as parameter in function from container of abstract class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have the following class hierarchy plus a wrapper class:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  virtual void init() = 0;
};

struct DerivedA : Base {
  void init() override {
    // do something specific to DerivedA
  }
};

struct DerivedB : Base {
  void init() override {
    // do something specific to DerivedB
  }
};

struct Wrapper{
  Base* _item;
};
```

Now, I would like to have a container of `Wrapper` (e. g. `std::vector<Wrapper>`) and a function `f` which expects two derived classes as parameters, like this:

```
void f(DerivedA* d1, DerivedA* d2) {
  std::cout << "A vs A" << std::endl;
}

void f(DerivedA* d1, DerivedB* d2) {
  std::cout << "A vs B" << std::endl;
}

void f(DerivedB* d1, DerivedB* d2) {
  std::cout << "B vs B" << std::endl;
}

void f(DerivedB* d1, DerivedA* d2) {
  std::cout << "B vs A" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Wrapper> items;
  items.emplace_back(new DerivedA());
  items.emplace_back(new DerivedB());
  items.emplace_back(new DerivedB());
  items.emplace_back(new DerivedA());

  for (auto i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j = i+1; j < items.size(); j++) {
      // do something wizh all item pairs
      f(items[i]._item, items[j]._item);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This does not compile because the compiler does expect a declaration of `f(Base* b1, Base* b2)`, which of course makes sense.

What I tried so far:

1. Use `enum class DerivedType { A, B, C };` to decipher the type of the derived class. This works but seems clumsy.
2. Use a templated version of `Wrapper` and store each template type in a different container, like `std::vector<Wrapper<DerivedX>>`. Again, this feels like I'm doing something wrong.
3. Use `std::variant<DerivedA, DerivedB> _item` in place of `Base* _item` in `Wrapper`. But I could not get `std::visit` to return a pointer to a dervied class the way I require it for `f` (because `operator()(DerivedX* d)` expects the same return to for any `X`).

What are possible ways to implement this? Does the solution I am looking for even exist?

Comment: Could you make `f` a virtual function of the classes? If so, that would solve the issue of the *first* argument (as that would become the `this` pointer, which would determine the function to be called *via* polymorphism). You would still need to address the case for the different possible second argument, though.

Comment: Look up multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Using an RTTI-based solution is also an option:

```
void f1(Base* d1, Base* d2) {
    const auto& t1 = typeid(*d1);
    const auto& t2 = typeid(*d2);

    if (t1 == typeid (DerivedA) && t2 == typeid (DerivedA)) {
        std::cout << "A vs A" << std::endl;
    }

    if (t1 == typeid (DerivedA) && t2 == typeid (DerivedB)) {
        std::cout << "A vs B" << std::endl;
    }

    if (t1 == typeid (DerivedB) && t2 == typeid (DerivedA)) {
        std::cout << "B vs A" << std::endl;
    }

    if (t1 == typeid (DerivedB) && t2 == typeid (DerivedB)) {
        std::cout << "B vs B" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming no derived classes from `DerivedA`.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::variant`, it would be:

```
struct Wrapper{
  std::variant<DerivedA, DerivedB> _item;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Wrapper> items {
    { DerivedA()}, 
    { DerivedB()},
    { DerivedB()},
    { DerivedA()}
  };

  for (auto i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j = i+1; j < items.size(); j++) {
      // do something with all item pairs here
      std::visit([] (auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { f(&lhs, &rhs); }, items[i]._item, items[j]._item);
    }
  }
}
```